# Netty4 websockets: getting IllegalStateException from HttpObjectDecoder if we attempt to send a message too quickly after websocket connect

Tags: websocket, netty

UPDATED w/ additional CODE

Using Netty 4.0.12, we're getting an IllegalStateException from HttpObjectEncoder if we try to send a message immediately after our websocket is connected (see exception at the bottom).  If I sleep a 1 - 2 secs, then everything is fine.

I thought this was because we weren't handling the ChannelFuture properly, but I believe I've fixed that by waiting for the future to be completed using the following logic on the ChannelFuture to ensure the connect is completed before we attempt to use it.

Unfortunately, that didn't fix it.  If anyone knows what might be causing this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Bob

=====================

WEBSOCKET CREATION

```
public synchronized Channel createWebSocket(String id, NettyClientConnection connection) throws Exception
{
    URI serverUri = connection.getServerUri();
    final ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(connection);

    this.getBootstrap().handler(new ChannelPipelineInitializer(serverUri, clientHandler));

    ChannelFuture future = this.getBootstrap().connect(serverUri.getHost(), serverUri.getPort());

    // verify connect has completed successfully
    NettyUtils.waitForChannelCompletion(future, "connecting websocket");

    Channel websocket = future.channel();

    return websocket;
}
```

PIPELINE INIT

```
public class ChannelPipelineInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> 
{
    private URI _serverUri = null;
    protected URI getServerUri(){return this._serverUri;}

    private ClientHandler _clientHandler = null;
    protected ClientHandler getClientHandler(){return this._clientHandler;}

    public ChannelPipelineInitializer(URI serverUri, ClientHandler clientHandler)
    {
        this._serverUri = serverUri;
        this._clientHandler = clientHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception 
    {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        boolean handleCloseFrames = false;
        WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(this.getServerUri(), WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, null);

        final WebSocketClientProtocolHandler websocketHandler = new WebSocketClientProtocolHandler(handshaker, handleCloseFrames);

        DefaultEventExecutorGroup nettyExecutor = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);

        pipeline.addLast(PipelineConstants.HttpClientCodec, new HttpClientCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(PipelineConstants.HttpAggregator, new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
        pipeline.addLast(PipelineConstants.WebSocketClientProtocolHandler, websocketHandler);
        pipeline.addLast(PipelineConstants.ThingworxMessageCodec, new ThingworxMessageCodec());

        // use netty executor to free up initial IO thread
        pipeline.addLast(nettyExecutor, this.getClientHandler());
    }
}
```

CHANNEL WAIT LOGIC

```
public static void waitForChannelCompletion(ChannelFuture future, String operationMessage) throws IOCompletionException
{
    future.awaitUninterruptibly();

    // Now we are sure the future is completed.
    if (future.isDone())
    {
        if (future.isCancelled())
        {
            String errorMsg = String.format("IO Operation has been cancelled [operation: %s]", operationMessage);
            throw new IOCompletionException(errorMsg);
        }
        else if (future.isSuccess() == false) 
        {
            String errorMsg = String.format("IO Operation failed [operation: %s]", operationMessage);
            throw new IOCompletionException(errorMsg, future.cause());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // future should be done, otherwise there's a problem
        String errorMsg = String.format("IO Operation never completed [operation: %s]", operationMessage);
        throw new IOCompletionException(errorMsg);
    }
}
```

## EXCEPTION STACK

```
2013-11-21 13:32:16.767-0500 [ERROR] [c.t.t.t.SendTask] [T: pool-2-thread-9] Client_9 Attempt to send message failed. java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encode(HttpObjectEncoder.java:80) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Encoder.encode(HttpClientCodec.java:94) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na] Wrapped by: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:193) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:645) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:699) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:638) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:115) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:645) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:699) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:638) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:115) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write(MessageToMessageCodec.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:645) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$2000(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:29) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:906) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101) ~[netty-all-4.0.12.Final.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: Can you show me the whole code where  you do the handshake etc ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what's happening is this

1) Client sends upgrade request

2) Server sends upgrade response to client, fires local HANDSHAKE_COMPLETED event

3) Upstream server handlers hear event, start sending websocket frames to client

4) Client receives upgrade response (HTTP 101)

5) Client receives first websocket frame before #4 reaches websocket handshaker

***HttpClientCodec throws exception here while processing websocket frame, causing websocket handshaker to close connection***

6) Client processes upgrade response and removes HttpClientCodec *(oops, too late)*

I'm also seeing this with 4.0.14.Final, but with HttpClientCodec at the front of the pipeline.

** UPDATE **

This is fixed, btw: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2173